# Poisson distribution - more than 2 points with same probability mass?!

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For a random variable X with Poisson distribution is it possible that:

$$p_X(i) = p_X(j) = p_X(s) \tag {*} $$

for some different integers $i < j < s$?

I think it's not possible but... How can we (most simply) prove it?

Comment: It is a consequence of the probability mass function being strictly increasing up to a particular value and then strictly decreasing from the next value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $p_{X}(k)=\lambda^{k}e^{-\lambda}/k!$. By considering $p_{X}(k+1)/p_{X}(k)$ show that $p_{X}$ is increasing for $k\leq \lambda-1$ and decreasing for $k>\lambda-1$.

Comment: Thanks. You should say "strictly increasing/decreasing", I think.